# Why does the Cycles render engine add this cube?

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I am very new to using Blender. I was wondering why the Cycles render engine add this cube to my rendered picture when it doesn't do this with the EEVEE engine. Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: Hello could you please share your file?

Comment: okay i restarted the application and now its gone. i guess i should have tried that first hahaha.

Comment: OK that was weir....   ;)